# Typescripts can not find ng.route.IRouteProvider in VS Code, reporting: Namespace 'angular' has no exported member 'route'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typing

I am transferring my Angularjs v1 project to Angular v2. With @types from NPM, I couldn't diminish the error reporting for "**Namespace 'angular' has no exported member 'route'.**"

I did find the d.ts file from ./node_modules/_@types_angular-route@1.3.4@@types/index.d.ts, in which, the 'route' are declared. However, along with @types/angular, it seems that @types/angular-route could not handle the error reporting properly in VS Code.

Here are my package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/angular-route": "^1.3.4",
    "@types/angular": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-route": "^1.6.4",
    "angular": "^1.6.4"
  }
}
```

Here is the 'app.route.ts', the error reporting is from the 4th line:

```
module MyModules {
"use strict";

function routeConfig($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider){ 
    $routeProvider
        .when("/search", {
            templateUrl: "MyModules/views/_search.html",
            controller: "SearchController",
            controllerAs: "vm"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/search"
        });
}

routeConfig.$inject = ["$routeProvider"]

angular
    .module("MyModules")
    .config(routeConfig);
}
```

Comment: If I added `///<reference path="../../node_modules/@types/angular-route/index.d.ts"/>` on top of the app.route.ts, the error reporting will go away, but if I added `///<reference path="../../node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts"/>` together with it, errors come again. So the d.ts can not handle dependency or extension?